# updating an auto_now DateTimeField in a related model

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to update a related models timestamp when saving a record. Here are my models:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    issueTitle = models.CharField()
    issueDescription = models.TextField()
    issueCreatedDateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.issueTitle

class IssueHistory(models.Model):
    fk_issueID = models.ForeignKey(Issue)
    issuehistoryDetail = models.TextField()
    issuehistoryCreatedBy = models.ForeignKey(User)
    issuehistoryCreatedDateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fk_issueID

    def save(self): #1.1
        # Call parent's `save` function
        # Record is saved like it would be normally, without the override
        super(IssueHistory, self).save() #1.2   

        #This is where i believe i should be updating the "issueCreatedDateTime" to the same datetime
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927/updating-an-auto-now-datetimefield-in-a-parent-model-w-django) describes want but the final code wasn't posted (unless I am misunderstanding it).

To further clarify, this is the desired order of events:

1. Save a new issue history record
2. save() is overridden, uses the custom
3. IssueHistory record is saved
4. Related Issue record's "issueCreatedDateTime" field is updated to the current datetime

How should i do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django updating foreignKey field before saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770424/django-updating-foreignkey-field-before-saving)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.

    # Set Issue issueCreatedDateTime to the same as IssueHistory issueCreatedDateTime
    self.fk_issueID.issueCreatedDateTime = self.issuehistoryCreatedDateTime
    # Save the Issue
    self.fk_issueID.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked however the model i detailed was a subset of my full model. When I click save now, it also updates the field "issueCreatedDateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)" which should only occur on record creation?   (if this should be a new question/post, let me know)

Comment: My mistake...it fully works! Thanks! awesome. The line"self.fk_issueID.issueCreatedDateTime = self.issuehistoryCreatedDateTime" should really be using the issueUpdatedDateTime field though (for what i want anyway)

Comment: Also check the documentation about how to override the **save()** method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods , i.e. using the right method signature, to pass parameters: `def save(self, *args, **kwargs)/super().save(*args, **kwargs)`