# django updating foreignKey field before saving

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have the following models.py

```
class Notebook(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Maximum 250 characters')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Page(models.Model):
    Notebook = models.ForeignKey(Notebook)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique_for_date='pub_date')
    tags = TaggableManager()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(slef):
        reutrn self.title
```

As it is clear, a page belongs to a notebook and I have `last_modified` field in `Notebook` model.

When I add a new page to my db, I want `last_modified` field updated to time of insert of the page.

I know that I have to do some stuff by overrding the `save` method of `Page` class. But not sure of how to get fields from different class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) in the `last_modified` field and extend the `Page` model `save` method so it calls the `Notebook` instance `save` method which will update the `last_modified` value automatically:

```
class Notebook(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Maximum 250 characters')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Page(models.Model):
    notebook = models.ForeignKey(Notebook)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique_for_date='pub_date')
    tags = TaggableManager()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(Page, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.notebook.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like @Gonzalo answer, just try to replace `self.notebook.save()` by `self.notebook.save(update_fields=['last_modified'])` if you are using Django > 1.4

Or you can use the `post_save` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save)

Or you can define `last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)` in the `Page` object and get the last modified from `NoteBook` instance with a simple orm query. (This depends on your requirements)

```
from django.db.models import Max

class Notebook(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Maximum 250 characters')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def get_last_modified(self):
        return self.page_set.aggregate(max=Max('last_modified'))['max']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer above will help but if you would use a form in your template to add page(if you want to users to add pages, probably you will), you will have to do a few more steps.
In adding page part of views.py you should use a code like this:

```
def tek(request, slug):
    Notebook = get_object_or_404(Notebook, slug=slug)
    form2 = EntryForm(request.POST or None)

    if form2.is_valid():
        page = form2.save(commit=False)
        page.Notebook = Notebook
        Notebook.last_modified = page.pub_date
        Notebook.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Page/%s'%(page.slug))
    ctx = {}

    return render(request, "app/page.html", ctx)
```

I don't know your exact aim on your app so I just wrote a spont code. You should customize it.

Comment: I disagree, this feature is best implemented in the model, so that it works consistently between the site admin, REST API and the view above.